# Can I Get the Windows Explorer Toolbar Back in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I want the Windows Explorer Toolbar from Windows 7 back:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IlLT.jpg]

Not a fan of the controversial Ribbon UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools, like [OldNewExplorer, which can disable Ribbons](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/), this brings back the old command bar:

[image]

Comment: Slick. Now I wonder if there's a way to disable ribbons natively without installing a utility. Maybe somewhere in the registry? Maybe I should've Google'd "disable ribbons ui" instead of "bring back"Windows Explorer toolbar". My Google Fu is not strong today.

Comment: this is not possible without any 3rd party tool

Comment: Duly noted! Any of those utilities able to customize this toolbar? Would love to also add "New Text File" for easy one-click access.

Comment: try if this still works in Windows 8: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-windows-explorer-command-bar-aka-folder-band-or-toolbar-in-windows-vista-and-7-add-cut-copy-paste-delete-rename-undo-and-many-other-useful-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

If you go in Windows Explorer and press F11, it will go into full screen, which will show the old style.

Comment: Actually, that's not necessarily true. Sometimes pressing f11 in explorer can HIDE the toobar.

Comment: That did kinda work, once the address bar auto-hides, but it still makes those options two steps away. I just want it there always, regardless of window size.

Comment: That's the only way I can think of if you don't want to use other tools.